# C++ forward class declaration generator

Tags: c++, code-generation, forward-declaration

Is there a tool that would go through a list of files and would spit out a header file with forward declarations of classes it encounters? Ideally, I would like to integrate it into Visual C++'s build process.

Comment: You could do this fairly simply as a find in files search, but that would be interactive.  Conversely you could do the search in AWK or any scripting language.

Comment: You're doing in wrong.  Just include the correct headers, and if you have circular header dependencies use forward declaration headers ala <iofwd>

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I got all the feedback I needed. Using forward declarations when they're needed is fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. But I guess that all that you want are class names, so grep, awk or something like that would do the job.

Comment: I need class names + their template declarations. I don't know if that would be possible without using an actual parser?

Comment: I want to generate a single header file with all the class declarations, so I can include it and have less forward-declaration-clutter in my headers. Why does it seem odd? Is it a bad practice?

Comment: It seems odd that your project would require more than just a couple forward declarations.

Comment: This would force a rebuild of the entire project every time you add a class. It's better for each header to forward declare just the classes it needs - if your classes are a reasonable size, then they shouldn't need more than a handful of declarations.

Comment: @John Dibling: It's not like my project **needs** those declarations per se. It's just about me being used to C# "no-header, no-declaration bliss" over the years and wanting to see if it would be a good approach for C++. From the feedback I got it seems it woudln't.

Answer (score 0):

You can [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) and save replacements to a file.